# Use absolute coordinates with transform translate

Tags: javascript, html, css

I can make a box that follows the mouse with the following.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', e.clientY + 'px');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  background-color: blue;
  
  transform: translate(calc(var(--mouse-x) - 50%), calc(var(--mouse-y) - 50%));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

but as soon as the element is not positioned at the top left, it breaks.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', e.clientY + 'px');
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  margin-left: 150px;
  
  background-color: blue;
  
  transform: translate(calc(var(--mouse-x) - 50%), calc(var(--mouse-y) - 50%));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

How can I use absolute coordinates with a transform? I don't want to use left/top/position: fixed/absolute because I need to preserve the position of the element in the flow.

I could use JavaScript to grab the central position and then use that infomation to get the correct center.

```js
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-x', e.clientX + 'px');
    document.documentElement.style.setProperty('--mouse-y', e.clientY + 'px');
});

window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
    box.setAttribute('style', `
      --center-x: ${rect.left + (rect.width / 2)}px;
      --center-y: ${rect.top + (rect.height / 2)}px;
    `);
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  
  margin-left: 150px;
  
  background-color: blue;
  
  transform: translate(calc(var(--mouse-x) - var(--center-x)), calc(var(--mouse-y) - var(--center-y)));
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

This works, but it's not ideal and easily broken if anything else in the page changes. It also slows down with more elements, and I'd like it to be as fast as possible. It there a better way to do this? I'm fine using CSS/Vanilla JS.

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `translate()` please I would recommend you to use the `left` and `top` properties in CSS. They can help you position an element based on coordinates.

```js
window.addEventListener('load', (e) => {
    const box = document.querySelector('.box');
    const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
    document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
    box.style.left = e.pageX + 'px';
    box.style.top = e.pageY + 'px';
});
});
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position:absolute;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

The `transform: translate()` property works relative to the size of the box but the `left` and `top` properties don't. It can also be much faster in some cases because in your code there was a lot of calculation going on. Whereas, this is straightforward.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It does what I need, but I'd like to avoid using top and left so I can smoothly animate between entering and exit the content flow.

Comment: Okay @Jack so you want to use translate instead of top and left?

Comment: Ideally, but I don't know how possible that is to do while remaining fast. I'm going to be having as many elements moving as possible so speed is really important to me. I found that when I use top and left everything slowed way down. I would have to do more testing to see what the best way of doing it is.

Comment: @Jack i am not sure if i know a way around

Comment: @Jack would you like to see an answer with `requestAnimationFrame()`?? It is usually used to make high quality animations so we can use that here as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution using the `requestAnimationFrame()` function. The `requestAnimationFrame()` method tells the browser that you wish to perform an animation and requests that the browser calls a specified function to update an animation before the next repaint. For higher refresh rate monitors, this function will be run more the number of times to match the refresh rate.

More information [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame)

Here is the working solution:

```js
const box = document.querySelector('.box');
const rect = box.getBoundingClientRect();
let mouseX = 0;
let mouseY = 0
document.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => {
  mouseX = e.pageX + 'px';
  mouseY = e.pageY + 'px';
})

function mouseMove() {
  box.style.left = mouseX;
  box.style.top = mouseY;
  requestAnimationFrame(mouseMove)
};
mouseMove()
```

```css
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you! Because your answer still uses left and right, I'm not going to accept it. But thanks though